# Vim command Scroll Up and down - Does a plugin exist for this?

Tags: vim, scroll

I have been using vim for a couple of months now however my current workflow involves continuously scrolling down and up. For that i use `Ctrl+f` and `Ctrl+b`
So whenever I use the Ctrl+f combination the new text appears on the center of the screen. I wanted to know if there was a way for vim to always have a light coloured line in the center of screen (so i could use the line as a reference to the new content whenever i press ctrl+f (scroll half screen)). I know this request sounds odd but I am curious if such a feature exists?

Comment: Do you really a constant "highlight" on the center of the window? Why isn't the current line highlight enough? (sincere question)

Comment: See [this](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_current_line) for `cursorline`.

Comment: Are you referring to the current line highlight (set cursorline )? In that case i might be at row 1 and i need the new line or highlighting to be at row 700 as i am scrolling down half page

Comment: You probably already know this, but just in case, you can use `ctrl-E` to scroll down and `ctrl-Y` to scroll up one line at a time. I find this smother and easier to follow then scrolling an entire screen.

Comment: There's also Ctrl-U and Ctrl-D for half-screen scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this smooth scroll plugin: https://github.com/terryma/vim-smooth-scroll  I think it may solve your problem.

Comment: Interesting plugin, but this is not an answer to the question. Should be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your `.vimrc` or in a script:

```
augroup HlMid
  autocmd!
  autocmd CursorMoved * :call HighlightMiddle() 
augroup END

function! HighlightMiddle()
  normal! M                                                           
  execute "match search /\\%".line('.')."l/"                          
  normal! ^O                                                          
endfunction!
```

EDIT: As [rgoliveira](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4176370/rgoliveira) stated in the comment that could interfere with `match` command. You need only to remove the `autocommand` and make it back whenever you use it:

*Remove:*

```
:autocmd! HlMid CursorMoved *
```

*Reload:*

```
:autocmd HlMid CursorMoved * :call HighlightMiddle()
```

---

For the last command in the function *`normal! ^o` you get `^o`* by typing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>

Comment: Ha, clever use of  `normal`! I was looking into `match`ing the `scroll`'th line below.

Comment: Also, isn't a call to `match` needed to clear the previous highlighting?

Comment: Isn't it easier to just call `match` with no arguments to clear the highlight from the last call? [See `:match` docs](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#match-highlight)

Comment: You need to understand how the `autocmd` works and you will answer yourself ;)